# PROBLEM with dnsmasq

Tags: dnsmasq

Hi there I'm having problems with this command...

I made the dnsmasq.conf file this way:

```
interface=wlan0mon
dhcp-range= 192.168.1.2, 192.168.1.30, 255.255.255.0, 12h
dhcp-option=3, 192.168.1.1
dhcp-option=6, 192.168.1.1
server= 8.8.8.8
log-queries
log-dhcp
listen-address= 127.0.0.1
```

when I hit the command

```
sudo dnsmasq -C dnsmasq.conf -d
```

I get this:

```
dnsmasq: started, version 2.84rc2 cachesize 150
dnsmasq: compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt DBus no-UBus i18n IDN2 DHCP DHCPv6 no-Lua TFTP 
conntrack ipset auth cryptohash DNSSEC loop-detect inotify dumpfile
dnsmasq-dhcp: DHCP, IP range 192.168.1.2 -- 192.168.1.30, lease time 12h
dnsmasq: using nameserver 8.8.8.8#53
dnsmasq: no servers found in /etc/resolv.conf, will retry
dnsmasq: read /etc/hosts - 6 addresses
```

My resolv.conf file contain this:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8) # DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN # 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver. # run "resolvectl status" to see details about the actual nameservers.
    namserver 192.168.1.1
    namserver fe::d635:1dff:fe1e:463f%wlan0
    search homenet.telecomitalia.it
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of your `/etc/resolv.conf` file please.

Comment: Here you go:



# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "resolvectl status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

Comment: Could you add that to your question with formatting? Can you explain what you think is wrong? The output of the command looks like what I would expect. It does not look like you have a line in your `/etc/resolv.conf` with `nameserver` in it, so dnsmasq not finding any servers in `/etc/resolv.conf` looks accurate. You should update the question with what you think is the expected behavior vs. what you are actually seeing happening.

Comment: I see I actually have stuff in there I got it wrong before...

Here you go: # Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8) # DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN # 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver. # run "resolvectl status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

namserver  192.168.1.1
namserver   fe::d635:1dff:fe1e:463f%wlan0
search homenet.telecomitalia.it

Comment: Can you edit the actual question and add the `/etc/resolv.conf` with formatting please?

Comment: Sure, done! Also I was trying to mess with vim /etc/resolv.conf but it won't let me save...

Comment: This could just be a typo, but your file has `namserver` instead of `nameserver` for both entries. As far as your issue with vim goes. `/etc/resolv.conf/` is likely read only and owned by root, which means you will need to open the file with sudo privileges `sudo vim /etc/resolv.conf` and then when writing the file you will have to force the write by adding a `!` after the `:w` like so `:w!`

Comment: Thank you Natolio!
I did manage to alter the file but probably I wrote the wrong stuff... I get dnsmasq: config error is REFUSED
How would you write it?

Comment: The file actually looked fine to me besides what I assume was a typo, but the comment on the file says it's automatically generated by resolvconf. I've never dealt with this before, but I think that you may need to edit a file under `/etc/resolvconf/resolvconf.d`. Then do a `systemctl restart resolvconf.service`. If there are files in `/etc/resolvconf/resolvconf.d` post them in your original question so more information is available.

Comment: Thanks Natolio, I did post it already, is at the end of the original  question. I guess I need to change the nameserver values and I'm not sure what "search" is

Comment: I believe you posted `/etc/resolv.conf`, but based on the comment at the top of that file I believe you are running `resolvconf.service` which I think automatically generated your `/etc/resolv.conf`. I think that you should be able to edit `/etc/resolvconf/resolvconf.d/head` and then `systemctl restart resolvconf.service` so those changes take effect. The `search` line allows you to do shortname DNS lookups on hosts that have that domain. Yours is set to `homenet.telecomitalia.it` so if a host had the name host1.homenet.telecomitalia.it, you could successfully ping host1 instead of the fqdn.

Comment: Alright so I modified both  (they were empty) and I wrote in them nameserver 8.8.8.8
When I connect with a device I don't have connection and the dnsmasq is saying:
<pre>dnsmasq: query[A] play googleapis.com from 192.168.1.2
dnsmasq: config error is REFUSED <code>